# ReactJS, React-admin 3.3.0. Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(Layout)))"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to connect `react-admin` to my `react-redux` app and getting this error.

> Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(Layout)))". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(Layout))) in connect options.

There is my admin page component:

```
export const AdminPage = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={createAdminStore({ dataProvider, history })}>
            <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} history={history} title="My Admin">
                <Resource
                    name="halls"
                    list={HallList}
                    edit={HallEdit}
                    create={HallCreate}
                />
            </Admin>
        </Provider>
  );
};
```

The thing is that if I remove react-admin lib via `yarn remove react-admin`, and then upload it again via `yarn add react-admin` - it works nice. But after `yarn` command and packages updates this error starts to appear again.

Comment: Solved. The problem was in redux, after update of it all works.

Comment: To be more specific, it didn't work for me with these versions: `"react-admin": "3.14.3"` and `"react-redux": "7.2.2"` but worked with these: `"react-admin": "3.14.3"` and `"react-redux": "7.2.3"`.